# In C#, how to access a dictionary with items of anonymous type wrapped inside of an "object" type

Tags: c#

In C#, I am reading a property `Config` of type `IDictionary<string, object>`. I am unable to access the information inside the `object`elements. It should be a JSON string, however it is wrapped as object.

In VisualStudio's Immediate window, typing `Config` outputs:

```
Count = 1
    [0]: {[items, Count = 3]}
```

Drilling down into items:

```
var configItemsElement  = Config["items"]
```

Typing `configItemsElement` in Immediate window outputs:

```
Count = 3
    [0]: {[1, {{ value = SeoChoiceInherit, sortOrder = 1 }}]}
    [1]: {[2, {{ value = SeoChoiceYes, sortOrder = 2 }}]}
    [2]: {[3, {{ value = SeoChoiceNo, sortOrder = 3 }}]}
```

and typing `configItemsElement.ToString()` returns this type information:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,<>f__AnonymousType7`2[System.String,System.Int32]]
```

This is as far as I get. I cannot access the elements of `configItemsElement`. For instance

```
configItemsElement[1]
```

results in `error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

In VisualStudio's "Autos" window, the information for `configItemsElement`is

```
configItemsElement
Value: Count = 3
Type: object {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, <>f__AnonymousType7<string, int>>}
```

What does this `type` information mean? It hints at a dictionary, yet applying a key with `configItemsElement[1]` results in the error above. How can I cast this object to a type I can use? Any cast I try results in errors.

**EDIT:** 
I have no access to the code providing the `.Config` property, but I can see in SQL explorer the data being read into the property. SQL Explorer shows this data:

```
{"items":[{"id":1,"value":"SeoChoiceInherit"},{"id":2,"value":"SeoChoiceYes"},{"id":3,"value":"SeoChoiceNo"}]}
```

Making `configItemsElement` dynamic, and accessing `.value`, as suggested in symap's answer, like:

```
dynamic configItemsElement = Config["Items"];
var myString =configItemsElement.value;
```

results in error:

```
''object' does not contain a definition for 'value''
```

which I understand, since `configItemsElement` should contain a dictionary . But, as mentioned above, accessing dictionary elements doesn`t work either.

Comment: It may help showing the cast attempts with the errors

Comment: Please, share how it's declared in code

Comment: It seems like `configItemsElement` is a dictionary where `string` is key and value is of type `int`. Can you show us structure  `configItemsElement`

Comment: I have no access to the code which provides the .Config property of type `IDictionary<string, object>`. However I can see in SQL explorer the data which seems to be read into this property:

{"items":[{"id":1,"value":"SeoChoiceInherit"},{"id":2,"value":"SeoChoiceYes"},{"id":3,value":"#SeoChoiceNo"}]}

Comment: @Attersson: for instance `configItemsElement as string` gives `null`. I also defined some classes to mirror the contained types and cast explicitely to this, and I get 'specified cast not valid`

Comment: Exact code + exact error please? (unless you already found a solution)

Comment: @Attersson: no solution yet. What else do you need in order to hep?

Comment: How does the data get deserialized into IDictionary<string, object> in the first place?

Comment: @Darkonekt I don't know, I have no access to the code, I am just using the API.

Comment: Just deserialize to the a valid type and it will work, like shf301 said

Comment: @Attersson: I would, if I could get to the string value. Getting to the simple string value of `configItemsElement` would already help. `(string)configItemsElement` gives null.

Comment: So you are calling a JSON API? Or are you getting the dictionary from a third party dll?

Comment: @Attersson: configElement.ToString() returns the type information, not the content. I found a working solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question since the valuable input I received pointed me to the right direction, yet did not give me a working solution. I am rather new to Stackoverflow, so if there is something I should learn about this, please let me know.

Also, although I found a working solution, I do not understand why the suggestions by @symaps and @shf301 do not work in this case. This is why I am grateful for further input.

The way I finally got it to work is to:

- declare my own type for the anonymous type
- cast `configItemsElement` to IEnumerable
- iterate over the dictionary inside of `configItemsElement`
- get the 'inner item' of each dictionary item using reflection
- cast the 'inner item' (of anonymous type) to dynamic
- and use reflection to access the 2 properties of the 'inner item' (`value` and `sortOrder`) to add them to a new list

This is my working code:

```
...

public class InnerItemType
{
    public int sortOrder { get; set;  }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

....

List<InnerItemType> listOptions = new List<InnerItemType>();

var configItemsElement = Config["items"] as IEnumerable;

foreach (var item in configItemsElement)
{
    dynamic innerItem = item.GetType().GetProperties()[1].GetValue(item);
    listOptions.Add(new InnerItemType() { 
        value = innerItem.GetType().GetProperties()[0].GetValue(innerItem), 
        sortOrder = innerItem.GetType().GetProperties()[1].GetValue(innerItem)
    });
}
...
```

Thanks to @symaps for pointing out that dynamics need to be used. Thanks to @shf301 for explaining that the anonymous type is the cause of the difficulty. This pointed me to the right direction.

However, curiously, the solution with just dynamics (without reflection) does not work as suggested, in my case, and I don't understand why this is.

`item.GetType().GetProperties()[1]` reveales the name of the innerItem:

```
{<>f__AnonymousType7`2[System.String,System.Int32] Value}
    ...
    Name: "Value"
```

but if I try to get to innerItem through a dynamic type using the property name like this:

```
foreach (dynamic item in configItemsElement)
{
    dynamic innerItem = item.Value;
```

I get an error `"'System.ValueType' does not contain a definition for 'Value'"`

Equally, if I try accessing `innerItem.value` and `innerItem.sortOrder` directly without reflection like so:

```
foreach (var item in configItemsElement)
{
    dynamic innerItem = item.GetType().GetProperties()[1].GetValue(item);
    listOptions.Add(new InnerItemType() { 
        value = innerItem.value, 
        sortOrder = innerItem.sortOrder
    });
```

gives the same error.

Do I misunderstand the works of `dynamic`? So, although I found a working solution, I would like to fully understand the underlying problem and I am grateful for further explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, <>f__AnonymousType7<string, int>>` means that you have a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).  Since anonymous types have no name (from C#'s perspective anyway, as you can see they get a generated name in the compiled code) there's no usable type for you to cast the values to.

Your issue occurred at the point where the configuration was parsed from JSON.  Anonymous types should generally only be used inside if a single methods.  If they leak out as `object` references you get the problems that you are having.  If possible the code that generated those configuration elements should be fixed to use a named type.

However if that's no possible your only fallback is to cast the values [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic).

Comment: The trouble I have is how to access the elements of the dictionary. Even when I make `configItemsElement` dynamic, still `configItemsElement[1]` for instance throws.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic to access the members without type checking.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ObjectDictionary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IDictionary <string, object>  dict= new Dictionary<String, object>();
            dict.Add("abc", new {value = "blah", sortOrder = 1});

            dynamic a = dict["abc"];
            Console.WriteLine(a.value);
            Console.WriteLine(a.sortOrder);
        }
    }
}
```

so your

```
var configItemsElement  = Config["items"];
```

would become

```
dynamic configItemsElement = Config["Items"];
var myString =configItemsElement.value;
```

Looking at your question the data does not appear to be stored as Json. If you need it as json then you would need to reconstruct the json. 
You could probably use a json Serializer

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configItemsElement, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: 'var myString =configItemsElement.value' gives me an error `''object' does not contain a definition for 'value''`. Please see my edit with some additional info.

Comment: P.S.: No I don't need the data as JSON. I made this comment that the source data might be JSON in case it helps understanding the problem.

Comment: Serializing it gives me a string of `"{\"1\":{\"value\":\"SeoChoiceInherit\",\"sortOrder\":1},\"2\":{\"value\":\"SeoChoiceYes\",\"sortOrder\":2},\"3\":{\"value\":\"SeoChoiceNo\",\"sortOrder\":3}}"`. I wonder how to access the individual elements (1, 2, 3) from the `dynamic configItemsElement`itself.

Comment: in your example code, `dynamic a = dict["abc"];` is exactly what does not work in my case. `dict`maps to my `configItemElement, but `configItemElement["1"]` throws `error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`